# Passing Exception to Higher Try/Catch in Nested Try/Catch [Nesting Required]

Tags: java, exception, nested, try-catch

I have the following scenario

```
try
{
   doSomething1();
   doSomething2();
   / * some other statements that might cause cause exceptions */

}
catch(Exception e)
{
  // log
}
```

Inside the doSomething1() there is also some nested try/catches. I want to know if we can pass the exception from inside the doSomething1() to the outermost try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that `doSomething1()` can throw an exception, by adding a `throws` clause to the method declaration and delegate exception handling to the method caller:

```
void doSomething1() throws IOException {

}
```

[Specifying the Exceptions Thrown by a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html)